# Disable force close vibrations

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, settings, vibration, force-close

I am developing some applications for Android and I'm getting some errors and force closes.

This is rather annoying, although not as much as annoying as the loud vibrations the phone does (a long vibration and 3 quick ones). This is very unpleasant for me and for my workmates.

I've set Sound >> Vibrate to "Never", but it keeps coming on and on and after searching through almost all the entire phone settings, a solution is still to find.

The device is the SGS running Froyo.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably not going to like my answer, but I don't think there's anything you can do about it. I've tried to turn this off myself in the past, but the Android OS is such that you will receive a force close vibration no matter what. Now, regarding your application actually force closing, here are my two best guesses (since I can't see any of your code):

1. You are trying to use a feature that requires documentation in the manifest file.
2. You are overburdening the UI stack by not threading processes that take a long time to accomplish (i.e. contacting a server and receiving data, handling remote data, etc.), which can be solved with [AsyncTasks](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html).

Also, if you are getting frequent force close errors, please use DDMS. It's an absolute God send for this kind of stuff. I know a lot of people who just try to "figure out" where they went wrong. Debugging is a skill in its own right.

Sorry I couldn't directly answer your question. I instead tried to pinpoint where else you may be going wrong with your applications, which, to me, would seem to be a bigger issue.

EDIT:

To show you how I arrived at this conclusion:

I firstly tried to look through all settings (including my Galaxy S manual), and obviously no cigar.

I noticed that there are two classes that a developer must look into to at least see if this vibration can be turned off programatically (for your specific program). These classes are the [Notification](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Notification.html) and [Vibrator](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Vibrator.html) classes. Upon inspection, you can see that there's nothing within these classes that will allow you to do that. It's a system property. Realizing that you must put in a "vibration" intent into the manifest in order to even manipulate the vibration should further prove this point:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE"/>
```

I wasn't really prepared to mess around with the actual Android low-level code so I brought the issue up with my friend (who has been messing around with the actual Android kernel and OS itself for a while) in order to validate my suspicion. He said that this property was built in. In other words, you would have to override the property within the OS itself in order to change the force close vibration. For me, that was the end of me trying to turn off this property.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The force closes and errors are not my main concern, I mean, I am building and testing some wrappers for native libraries, so I expect to get a lot of them; and it's not that I can't solve the problems, I just can't stand the vibration the phone makes when I can't :) (btw, I was simply making a cheap joke in the question...)

Thanks for answering though. Perhaps you can improve your answer by mentioning the steps you took when trying to turn it off and why you think there is nothing to do about it.

Comment: Haha I know exactly what you mean by the force close vibration being annoying as all hell. I'll edit my answer to show you what I attempted.